# Как создать грамотно SQL запрос?

Tags: sql

Приветствую народ.. Понимаю тупой вопрос, но все когда то были новичками..

Вообщем делаю форму обработки платежа, нужно сделать запрос такой:

После платежа, в таблице "history" значение поля "ym" менялось на 1 ,
Самое главное что бы это значение менялось только у того пользователя который произвел оплату.

p.s. В таблицу history сохраняются ИД пользователя, что бы его узнать обработчику нужно вытащить из поля email,
Объясню, Имеется страница истории где пользователю надо оплатить заказ, он заходит в историю и подтверждает оплату заказа (этому заказу присваивается уникальный номер), обработчик просит ввести майл пользователя, пользователь вводит его, после того как пользователь оплатить должно произойти процесс выше.

Comment: update вам чем не угодил? как я понял(а это было сложно): ввели емейл, обработчик вытаскивает емейл - по нему айди, а дальше "update history set ym = 1 where id = айди"

Comment: Спасибо, можешь помочь вытащить 'ID' транзакции?

Comment: я бы помог, зная твою структуры базы данных.по твоим словам это простой select типа "select IdTransaction from tablename". почитай про sql-запросы хотя бы, а то без таких базовых знаний невозможно работать с БД: http://fb.ru/article/145768/kak-sostavlyat-sql-zaprosyi---podrobnyie-primeryi